# Laravel: Testing controller and DB result

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

If I have a Laravel app with a form that when submitted is saved to a database, for example

*FORM*

```
// ---------- snip ------
data(){
    return {
        form:this.$inertia.form({
            '_method': 'POST',
            name: null,
            age: null,
        }, {
            bag: 'savePerson',
            resetOnSuccess: false,
        }),
    }
},
methods:{
    submit() {
        this.sending = true;
        this.form.post('/test/store').then((response) => {
            this.sending = false;
        });
    },
},
// ---------- snip ------
```

*CONTROLLER*

```
// ---------- snip ------
public function store(Request $req) 
{   
    // input field validation
    $v = Validator::make($req->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'age'  => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($v)->withInput($req->all());
    }
    
    // flash message
    if ($req->name == 'jada') {
         return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'beware of entanglement!!');
    }

    if ($req->name == 'chris') {
        $note = 'slapped';
    } elseif ($req->name == 'will') {
        $note = 'donut';
    } else {
        $note = 'boring';
    }
    
    // save to DB
    $person_obj = People::firstOrCreate([ 'name' => $req->name, 'age' => $req->age, 'note' => $note]);
    
    return redirect()->route('person', $person_obj->id)->with('success', 'Person saved');
} 
// ---------- snip ------
```

How would I test the controller function?

1. Test that that the validation works i.e.
   `[form:name = null, form:age = null]`
   `[form:name = 'alice', form:age = 'alice']` should fail
2. Test that the flash works i.e.
   `[form:name = 'jada', form:age = 50]` should return flash message *'beware of entanglement!!'*
3. Test rows saved in DB i.e. `[form:name = 'chris', form:age = 57]` should save in DB

```
 id  | name  | age |  note 
-----+-------+-----+--------
  ?  | chris | 57  | slapped
```

I understand that it is not proper unit testing since a DB is involved but I still would like to be able to simulate submitting a series of form entries and checking that the correct thing is being saved to the database. (Obviously the data is trivial in this joke example, but my actual Controller and DB is far more complicated and requires extensive testing)

Is this something that can be done easily in Laravel? and how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Use feature test instead of a unit test.

When testing using feature test, the ideal things to do is to use refresh database and have factory to create your dummy data. So your database will be empty each time a test case is running.

but when in any circumstances you can't refresh the database, and you use normal database then I have a workaround for you.

use DB::beginTransaction and DB::rollback in the end. but be careful, any unexpected DB::commit can be disastrous. But if you sure your code is fine, then you should give it a try

with that yes, you can test it with any available assertion and check if your data is in your DB or not using assertDatabaseHas

for the assertion list try read the documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#available-assertions

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#available-assertions

to test you end point create feature test and get the response of your end point like this

```
$response = $this->get('your end point to test')

// all of your assertion like
$response->assertSuccessful();
$this->assertDatabaseHas('table name', [data to assert]);
```